# Rx-Netty: Splitting a websocket frame into multiple fragments

Tags: rx-java, rx-netty

I've used Rx-Netty to implement a websocket server. When a java web socket client calls a server side API which returns a large set of data, I see following error on the client side:

> io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.

So I'm trying to implement fragmentation in the websocket response on the server side i.e. splitting the result set into multiple frames.

I have used following logic for fragmentation in java

```
private <T> List<WebSocketFrame> toFrames(T value, Serializer<T> serializer) {
  ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();

  ByteBufOutputStream stream = new ByteBufOutputStream(buf);
  serializer.toStream(stream, value);

  Integer bufSize = buf.readableBytes;
  List<WebSocketFrame> = new ArrayList<>();
  int noOfFrames = (int)Math.ceil(bufSize.toDouble / maxFrameSize);
  WebSocketFrame frame;
  if (noOfFrames == 1)      
  {
    frame = new TextWebSocketFrame(true, 0, buf);
    frames.add (frame);
  } else {
    // Set the initial read index before the first slice
    int readIndex = buf.readerIndex;
    for ( count = 1; count <= noOfFrames; count ++) {
      if (count == noOfFrames) {
        readIndex += maxFrameSize;
        frame = new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(true, 0, buf.slice(readIndex, bufSize - readIndex));
      }else if(count==1) {
        frame = new TextWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf.slice(readIndex, maxFrameSize));
      }else {
        // Bounce the reader index to next location in buffer
        readIndex += maxFrameSize;
        // Slice buffer of max frame size at the given index 
        frame = new ContinuationWebSocketFrame(false, 0, buf.slice(readIndex, maxFrameSize));
      }
      frames.add(frame);
    }
  }
  return frames;
}
```

But now I get the following error:

> io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: received non-continuation data frame while inside fragmented message

Not sure what I'm missing here, not able to find any example around this on internet.

Any help around this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a packet level inspection(maybe wireshark)
**Good Read:** https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg08245.html

Comment: 214                 // check opcode vs message fragmentation state 2/2
215                 if (fragmentedFramesCount != 0 && frameOpcode != OPCODE_CONT && frameOpcode != OPCODE_PING) {
216                     protocolViolation(channel, "received non-continuation data frame while inside fragmented message");
217                     return null;
218                 }